# How do I get CMake to link my test program to the netCDF library?

Tags: cmake

I have a project here: https://github.com/edhartnett/ncglm

It is a small C library for reading netCDF data files from the Geostationary Lightning Mapper. I have an autotools build which works fine, and I'm trying to add a CMake build.

The directory structure is simple, there is a main directory, a src directory, and a test directory.

In the main directory I have:

```
# This is the main cmake file for ncglm, a library to help read the
# netCDF data files from the Global Lightning Mapper (GLM) instrument
# on GOES-16 and GOES-17.
#
# Ed Hartnett 11/10/19

# This will use any cmake between 3.1 and 3.15, preferint later
# versions with updated policies.
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1...3.15)
if (${CMAKE_VERSION} VERSION_LESS 3.12)
  cmake_policy(VERSION ${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION})
endif()

# set the project name
project(ncglm VERSION 1.0)

#Add custom CMake Module
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/"
  CACHE INTERNAL "Location of our custom CMake modules.")

# Find netCDF.
include(FindNetCDF)

include_directories("${NETCDF_INCLUDES}")

# Create a config.h.
configure_file(config.h.cmake.in config.h)

# Turn on testing.
enable_testing()
include(CTest)

# Build in this subdirectory.
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

In the cmake directory I have this:

```
# - Find NetCDF
# Find the native NetCDF includes and library
#
#  NETCDF_INCLUDES    - where to find netcdf.h, etc
#  NETCDF_LIBRARIES   - Link these libraries when using NetCDF
#  NETCDF_FOUND       - True if NetCDF found including required interfaces (see below)
#
# Your package can require certain interfaces to be FOUND by setting these
#
#  NETCDF_CXX         - require the C++ interface and link the C++ library
#  NETCDF_F77         - require the F77 interface and link the fortran library
#  NETCDF_F90         - require the F90 interface and link the fortran library
#
# The following are not for general use and are included in
# NETCDF_LIBRARIES if the corresponding option above is set.
#
#  NETCDF_LIBRARIES_C    - Just the C interface
#  NETCDF_LIBRARIES_CXX  - C++ interface, if available
#  NETCDF_LIBRARIES_F77  - Fortran 77 interface, if available
#  NETCDF_LIBRARIES_F90  - Fortran 90 interface, if available
#
# Normal usage would be:
#  set (NETCDF_F90 "YES")
#  find_package (NetCDF REQUIRED)
#  target_link_libraries (uses_f90_interface ${NETCDF_LIBRARIES})
#  target_link_libraries (only_uses_c_interface ${NETCDF_LIBRARIES_C})

if (NETCDF_INCLUDES AND NETCDF_LIBRARIES)
  # Already in cache, be silent
  set (NETCDF_FIND_QUIETLY TRUE)
endif (NETCDF_INCLUDES AND NETCDF_LIBRARIES)

find_path (NETCDF_INCLUDES netcdf.h
  HINTS NETCDF_DIR ENV NETCDF_DIR)

find_library (NETCDF_LIBRARIES_C       NAMES netcdf)
mark_as_advanced(NETCDF_LIBRARIES_C)

set (NetCDF_has_interfaces "YES") # will be set to NO if we're missing any interfaces
set (NetCDF_libs "${NETCDF_LIBRARIES_C}")

get_filename_component (NetCDF_lib_dirs "${NETCDF_LIBRARIES_C}" PATH)

macro (NetCDF_check_interface lang header libs)
  if (NETCDF_${lang})
    find_path (NETCDF_INCLUDES_${lang} NAMES ${header}
      HINTS "${NETCDF_INCLUDES}" NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
    find_library (NETCDF_LIBRARIES_${lang} NAMES ${libs}
      HINTS "${NetCDF_lib_dirs}" NO_DEFAULT_PATH)
    mark_as_advanced (NETCDF_INCLUDES_${lang} NETCDF_LIBRARIES_${lang})
    if (NETCDF_INCLUDES_${lang} AND NETCDF_LIBRARIES_${lang})
      list (INSERT NetCDF_libs 0 ${NETCDF_LIBRARIES_${lang}}) # prepend so that -lnetcdf is last
    else (NETCDF_INCLUDES_${lang} AND NETCDF_LIBRARIES_${lang})
      set (NetCDF_has_interfaces "NO")
      message (STATUS "Failed to find NetCDF interface for ${lang}")
    endif (NETCDF_INCLUDES_${lang} AND NETCDF_LIBRARIES_${lang})
  endif (NETCDF_${lang})
endmacro (NetCDF_check_interface)

NetCDF_check_interface (CXX netcdfcpp.h netcdf_c++)
NetCDF_check_interface (F77 netcdf.inc  netcdff)
NetCDF_check_interface (F90 netcdf.mod  netcdff)

set (NETCDF_LIBRARIES "${NetCDF_libs}" CACHE STRING "All NetCDF libraries required for interface level")

# handle the QUIETLY and REQUIRED arguments and set NETCDF_FOUND to TRUE if
# all listed variables are TRUE
include (FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
find_package_handle_standard_args (NetCDF DEFAULT_MSG NETCDF_LIBRARIES NETCDF_INCLUDES NetCDF_has_interfaces)

mark_as_advanced (NETCDF_LIBRARIES NETCDF_INCLUDES)
```

Now in my test directory I am trying to build a test. It must link to the netcdf library and the ncglm library built in the src directory. I am trying this:

```
# This is the cmake build file for the test directory of the ncglm library.
#
# Ed Hartnett 11/10/19

enable_testing()
include_directories(${NETCDF_INCLUDES})
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
add_executable(tst_glm_read tst_glm_read.c un_test.h tst_utils.c)
target_link_libraries(tst_glm_read PRIVATE ${NETCDF_LIBRARIES}/libnetcdf.so)
target_link_libraries(tst_glm_read PRIVATE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/src/libncglm.a)
```

And it is not working. It does build the test, but does not run it:

```
ed@mikado:~/ncglm/build$ cmake -DNETCDF_INCLUDES=/usr/local/netcdf-c-4.7.2_hdf5-1.10.5/include -DNETCDF_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/netcdf-c-4.7.2_hdf5-1.10.5/lib .. && make
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found NetCDF: /usr/local/netcdf-c-4.7.2_hdf5-1.10.5/lib  
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ed/ncglm/build
Scanning dependencies of target ncglm
[ 20%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/ncglm.dir/glm_read.c.o
[ 40%] Linking C static library libncglm.a
[ 40%] Built target ncglm
Scanning dependencies of target tst_glm_read
[ 60%] Building C object test/CMakeFiles/tst_glm_read.dir/tst_glm_read.c.o
[ 80%] Building C object test/CMakeFiles/tst_glm_read.dir/tst_utils.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable tst_glm_read
[100%] Built target tst_glm_read
ed@mikado:~/ncglm/build$ make test
Running tests...
Test project /home/ed/ncglm/build
No tests were found!!!
```

How do I make it run the test.

Also, is there some better way to link to my libraries?

Also, how do I get a shared library with cmake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your `test/CMakeLists.txt` file. You are not expanding the `NETCDF_*` variables correctly; these require `${}`, not only `$`. Also, [`link_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/link_directories.html) accepts paths as arguments, not actual library files. Try putting the path containing the `netcdf` library here instead, or, simply put `${NETCDF_LIBRARIES}` in your call to `target_link_libraries()`. Another nitpick, prefer absolute paths (using `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}`) for these calls, so rearranging your project directories doesn't necessarily break your CMake:

```
enable_testing()
include_directories(${NETCDF_INCLUDES})
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
add_executable(tst_glm_read tst_glm_read.c un_test.h tst_utils.c)
target_link_libraries(tst_glm_read PRIVATE ${NETCDF_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. I still am not getting my test to run, but now it builds. I have modified my question based on this progress...